# ASCII decimal to string (on Arduino in C)

Tags: arrays, arduino, ascii, type-conversion

I recently got some new LoRa transceivers that format data as ASCII decimals (A = 65) when sent/received. So if I send the 40-byte payload "Transmission capability demonstration...", it would be output on the receiving end as:

```
84 114 97 110 115 109 105 115 115 105 111 110 32 99 97 112 97 98 105 108 105 116 121 32 100 101 109 111 110 115 116 114 97 116 105 111 110 46 46 46
```

... with a little for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  Serial.print(trx.read());
  Serial.print(" ");
  delay(1);
}
```

I'm decently new with data-type conversion on the Arduino platform (I have no experience handling ASCII) and haven't been able to find any simple method to convert this output into a string in C/C++. I've considered putting the complete payload into an array and converting them one-by-one using an ASCII hashmap but I would imagine there is an easier method.

***Update:*** I ended up using jacoblaw's answer and modified it a little bit for cleaner output. At one point I had tried to use a char cast on an array without declaring which element(s) to cast, so I- at the time- thought that you could not cast a byte to a char. Not that I'm not using an array like that, the method works. Thanks for the help @jacoblaw and @Groo. Here's what I'm using now:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      Serial.print((char)trx.read());
      delay(1);
  }
```

If you're going to reuse this, note that you'll have to change the second "for" condition to whatever your payload length is. Thanks again!

Comment: what type does `trx.read()` return ... `char`? Just in general, to me it seems a bit odd that you loop from `i=0; i<40` but never use `i` in the body of the loop. Are you guaranteed 40 bytes every time? Does `trx.read()` block?

Comment: So you want the get a string of the ascii characters that have the following decimal values? `84 114 97 110 115 109 105 115 115 105 111 110 32 99 97 112 97 98 105 108 105 116 121 32 100 101 109 111 110 115 116 114 97 116 105 111 110 46 46 46`

Comment: You should describe the problem better. It's not clear what exactly your problem is. Transceivers don't "format data as ASCII decimals", that phrase doesn't make any sense. When you call a specific overload of [`Serial.print`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print), *you* are sending the result of `trx.read()` as a number. You could, for example, use `Serial.print(char)x)` to print an actual character, or simply `Serial.write(buffer, len)` to send an array.

Comment: @yano that's my mistake, I should have explained that better. Yes, the way the transmitter is set up it will always be 40 bytes. "trx" is the name of the emulated serial address of the radio (created through a library called SoftwareSerial, and I believe this radio, in particular, responds to this command by sending the next byte in its memory available.

Comment: @jacoblaw I am trying to convert them to char (and eventually a string), which you seem to have done in your answer. I'm testing it now, thanks.

Comment: @Groo This is similar to jacoblaw's solution which I am now trying out, thanks for the help.

Comment: If you found your solution, post is as an answer not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you want. From what I understand you want the chars of what you receive from the transceiver

```
char rcv_str[40]; // Make sure this is large enough!
int temp; // From yuor example, it looks like trx.read() outputs ints
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  temp = trx.read();
  rcv_str[i] = (char)temp;  

  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.print(" ");
  delay(1);
}
```